# The second GetMouseButtonDown(0) is not triggered in Simulator mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The second GetMouseButtonDown(0) is not triggered when there is a short delay between clicks in Simulator mode in the Unity editor.

It works as intended when I switch to Game mode.

Tested on a scene with Camera, Light, and GameObject with this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Tester : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("DOWN");
        }
    }
}
```

Unity 2022.2.6

Windows 10

**UPDATE**

Works as intended on Android too. Seems like a Simulator problem.